# How measure spins along the same axis with relativity

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

Suppose that a pion decays into an electron and a positron. Now let the particles travel a large distance so that they are lightyears apart. The idea of the EPR paradox is that when you measure their spins along the same axis, then one will give result $0.5$ and the other one will give result $-0.5$. ‘Along the same axis’ would mean that the two axes (that is, the axis that we use to measure the electron and the axis that we use to measure the positron) are parallel. However, according to relativity, parallel lines are not really defined. So what is then the meaning of measuring along the same axis?

Comment: Look for [Infeld-Van der Waerden symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infeld%E2%80%93Van_der_Waerden_symbols) which are curved space-time analogue of Pauli matrices. The indices here correspond to only a local co-ordinate system... so measurement of spin along the same axis is meaningful only locally

Comment: @KP99 Consider to extent this comment to/ write this as an answer.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I have posted an answer, however, this answer is incomplete for now: I still don't know how to define measurement of spin along same direction for arbitrarily separated points in curved space-time

Comment: As a complementing comment: Even if you don't know the relative alignment of your spin coordinates (e.g. because you sent polarized photons through a fiber), you can still extract entanglement, measure quantum correlations, etc., by using a few copies of entangled pairs as "reference frames" (either beforehand or in the process of the measurement) -- you can find literature under this keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Quantum Mechanics, one can use [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) as a matrix representation of spin-1/2 operators. This is of course done in a standard Newtonian or special-relativistic setting. In a curved 3+1 dimensional space-time, we can think of Pauli matrices as a special case of Infeld-Van der Waerden symbols (${\sigma_{AA'}}^a$). Here, we have the isomorphism:
$$T_pM\cong_{iso}\mathbb{S}\otimes\mathbb{S}'$$for each $p\in M$, where $\mathbb{S}'$ and $\mathbb{S}$ are primed and un-primed spin space. The ${\sigma_{AA'}}^a$'s allow us to go from spin space to tangent vector space:
$$v^a={\sigma_{AA'}}^av^A\bar{v}^{A'}$$
$v^a\in T_pM$ being the null vector. Only if we choose a Minkowski tetrad at the point $p$, we will see that
$${\sigma_{AA'}}^a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(I,\vec{\sigma})$$
Thus $\sigma^i$'s correspond to the spatial directions in the tangent space only.

In flat space-time, we can also think of the spin operators $S^a$ as a linear super-position of [Pauli-Lubanski spin vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Lubanski_pseudovector) and they form the little group of the full Poincare symmetry group. In curved space-time, we don't have the Poincare group as our isometry group, but we can still do similar calculations in the tangent space.

Overall we see that indices in spin operators have meaningful interpretation strictly in the tangent space. In practice, if space-time is reasonable flat (like on surface of earth), we can extend our local Minkowski co-ordinate to a larger surrounding and still comment about measurement of spin along the same axis.